# Why are zombie processes invisible when doing ps -f on mac?

Tags: macos, process, fork, zombie-process

Given this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) >= 0) {
        if (pid == 0) {
            exit(0);
        } else {
            sleep(999);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

after running:

```
$ gcc -o zombie zombie.c
$ ./zombie &
$ ps -f
```

only the parent process is showing:

```
501 77474 74651   0  2:36PM ttys000    0:00.00 ./zombie
```

On Linux the same program shows this:

```
osboxes   6900  6835  0 13:37 pts/1    00:00:00 ./zombie
osboxes   6903  6900  0 13:37 pts/1    00:00:00 [zombie] <defunct>
```

Now, strangely, on OSX when starting more than one `zombie` programs..

```
$ ./zombie &
$ ./zombie &
$ ps -f
```

.. the zombie processes (in brackets) show up:

```
501 77653 74651   0  2:39PM ttys000    0:00.00 ./zombie
501 77664 74651   0  2:39PM ttys000    0:00.00 ./zombie
501 77667 77664   0  2:39PM ttys000    0:00.00 (zombie)
```

What's the reason for this?

Comment: I suspect this is a system bug. The first zombie does not appear to be returned by the call to `sysctl`. If there are two zombies in the system, later ones will be returned. Open a radar at bugreport.apple.com

Comment: thank you, @RobNapier, I opened a bug report. Let's see what the outcome will be.

Comment: Any updates on this? I cannot log in to bugreport.apple.com with my Apple ID.

Comment: @KarlMarklund I never heard back from Apple, unfortunately..